# the difference between future and present tenses

Tags: future-constructions

I cannot solve the question shown below.

the moment he **receives/will receive** this message, he must call me

which one is correct? and specifically why? thanks in advence.

Comment: Hello Melissa, Welcome to ELL! The first is correct: "the moment **he receives** ..." I think you may find [this page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future) very useful. It explains how we use the present tense to speak about the future. Though the reason **why** we do that is probably lost in the mists of time :-)

Comment: This seems like a common issue for English learners.  We say "at the moment he **receives**", and probably the best way to think about it is this: that moment is in the future *now*, but *at that moment*, his act of receiving is not in the future any more, but is the present.